# Prove a series that equals to $\frac{e}{e-1}$

Tags: analysis

Prove that 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}=\frac{e}{e-1}
$$

I think $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}$ should be a Riemann sum of a function but could find it. What is the trick in this question?

In addition, the equation holds true when it could interchange the limits, but how to prove it?

Comment: The result is the one you'd get by interchanging sum and limit, though right now I don't see an evident reason to justify it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes this is what I confused so I tried other ways but gained nothing.

Comment: Hint: $(1+\frac{k}{N})^{-N} = e^{-N}$, when N approach infinity.

Comment: @ZackNi your argument is correct when interchanging of limits holds true, but can you prove this?

Comment: For every $N$, let $u_N$ denote the function defined on $x>0$ by $$u_N(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}N\right)^{-N}$$ then, note first that $e^{x-x^2}\leqslant1+x\leqslant e^x$ for every $x>0$ hence, for every $k$ and $N$,
$$e^{-k}\leqslant u_N(k)\leqslant e^{k^2/N-k}$$
Second, each $u_N$ is decreasing hence, for every $N\geqslant2$ and $n\geqslant1$, $$\sum_{k>n}u_N(k)\leqslant\int_n^\infty u_N(x)dx=\frac{N}{N-1}\left(1+\frac{n}N\right)^{-N+1}\leqslant2u_N(n)\left(1+{}{}{}\frac{n}N\right)$$
Putting these together ...

Comment: ...  yields, for every $N\geqslant2$ and $n\geqslant1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_N(k)\leqslant e^{n^2/N}\sum_{k=0}^ne^{-k}+2u_N(n)\left(1+\frac{n}N\right)$$
hence $$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_N(k){}{}{}{}\leqslant\frac{e^{n^2/N}}{1-e^{-1}}+2e^{n^2/N}e^{-n}\left(1+\frac{n}{N}\right)$$ If $1\ll n\ll\sqrt{N}$ when $N\to\infty$, one gets $e^{n^2/N}\to1$, $e^{-n}\to0$ and $1+\frac{n}N\to1$ hence $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_N(k)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}=\frac{e}{e-1}.$$

Comment: @Gatsby : I've written a very short answer giving a justification for interchanging the limit and the sum. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^N = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{N}{{N\choose j}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^j} \ge 1 + {N\choose 1}\frac{k}{N} + {N\choose 2}\frac{k^2}{N^2} = 1 + k + \frac{N-1}{2N}k^2 \ge 1 + k + \frac{k^2}{4}$$
for $N\ge 2$. It follows that for any $M\ge 1$ we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} = \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}\le\sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+k+k^2/4}}.$$
Note that the RHS goes to zero as $M\rightarrow\infty$. Since $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}$, it follows that
\begin{align} &\limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}\right)} \\
&= \limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}\right)}\\
&\le\sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+k+k^2/4}}
\end{align}
i.e. $\limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}}\le \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}} + \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+k+k^2/4}}$. Now clearly
\begin{align} &\liminf\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}\right)} \\
&= \liminf\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}\right)}\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}
i.e. $\liminf\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}}\ge\sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}$. Letting $M\rightarrow\infty$ yields
$$\limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}}\le\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{e^{-k}}\le\liminf\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}}\\\implies \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{e^{-k}} = \frac{e}{e-1} $$
as desired.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you reach this step: $\limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N})\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}\right)}\le\sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+k+k^2/4}}$

Comment: Sure. In the line above I establish that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}}\le\sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+k+k^2/4}}$ for all $N$. Taking the $\limsup$ of both sides as $N\rightarrow\infty$, the RHS is independent of $N$ and thus remains constant, while the LHS becomes $\limsup\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+\frac{k}{N}\right)^{-N}} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}{e^{-k}}\right)}$.

Comment: Answer has been clarified a bit.